# jquery.min.js violates CSP for inline-style

Tags: jquery, http-headers, content-security-policy

I want to add CSP header to the webserver. I do not want to add 'unsafe-inline'. I have whitelisted the required inline scripts and styles using 'nonce' and this seems to work fine. But, there seems some issue with local jquery.min.js as it shows many CSP violation errors for inline styles. Upon checking the error in Chrome debugger window, it points to the following line of jquery.min.js :

```
a.innerHTML = u[1] + S.htmlPrefilter(o) + u[2],
```

I am not sure how this is related. Is there a way to eliminate these CSP violation errors for jquery.min.js without adding 'unsafe-inline'?

Details:

jquery.min.js version => `v3.5.1`

CSP policy => `default-src 'self' 'nonce-XXXX'; frame-ancestors 'self'; form-action 'self';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jquery has nothing to do with it. The `a.innerHTML = u[1] + S.htmlPrefilter(o) + u[2]` construction is used when you call `.html()` / `.append()` / `.prepend()` methods to insert an HTML code into DOM.

Since this causes a CSP violation, it means you insert HTML code containing inline styles: `<tag style='...'` or `<style>...</style>`. You have 2 opts:

- refactor JS-code to get rid of such inline style inserting.
- use [this hack](https://csplite.com/csp/test433/) to replace `style=` or `<style>...</style>` with their CSP-compatible equivalent.
  Idea ot the hack is to override `htmlPrefilter()` method, it's [empty](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/main/src/manipulation.js#L194) by default and intended to be redefined on your needs.

In case if `style=` causes CSP violation, you can use something like:

```
$.htmlPrefilter = function( html ) {
  // Really it have to be more complicated for replacing a tag's attributes only,
  // not just plain text replacement:
  return ( html + '' ).replace( / style=/gi, ' data-style=' );
  };
```

then when using `.html()` / `.append()` / `.prepend()` methods, all `style=inline_styles_here` attributes will be replaced with `data-style='inline_styles_here'` ones.

To CSP-safe apply real CSS styles to the tags you can use script like that:

```
$(function() {   // On page loads
  var tags = document.querySelectorAll('[data-style]');
  for (var tag of tags) {
    var attr = tag.getAttribute('data-style')
    var arr = attr.split(';').map( (el, index) => el.trim() );
    for (var i=0, tmp; i < arr.length; ++i) {
      if (! /:/.test(arr[i]) ) continue;        // Empty or wrong style
      tmp = arr[i].split(':').map( (el, index) => el.trim() );
      tag.style[ camelize(tmp[0]) ] = tmp[1];
      }
    }

  function camelize(str) {
    return str
      .split('-')
      .map( (word, index) => index == 0 ? word : word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1) )
      .join('');
    }

)}
```

Javascript is not my strong suit, rewrite the above script to use native jquery calls.

In case if `<style>...</style>` causes CSP violation, you can redefine `htmlPrefilter()` to replace `<style>` to the `<style nonce='value'>`, but you have to somehow pass the 'nonce' to the script.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!!! I have replaced all the style="..." inline styles in the javascript. I think the issue is as you pointed out the .html() and .append() calls in js code. Also there are .css() calls. So does something like element.css("width", "10px") result in inline style?

Comment: `element.css("width", "10px")` is [CSP-compatible](https://csplite.com/csp/test435/) and is not considered as inline styles.